# React, How to use a menu in a seperate file to call an api and return data to a different section of the main file

Tags: reactjs, function, file, menu, parameter-passing

I have a react app with a large menu, and as such am trying to move it to a seperate file from the main app.js

at the mement when you click on a link in the menu it call a node api and which returns some data, however when I try to seperate I can not get it to populate the results section which is still in the main script

Working version app.js

```
import React,{ useState } from 'react';

import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

import { Navigation } from "react-minimal-side-navigation";
import "react-minimal-side-navigation/lib/ReactMinimalSideNavigation.css";

export default class MyList extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      result: [],
    };
    this.callmyapi = this.callmyapi.bind(this);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
     <div class="menu">
     <Navigation
    
    onSelect={({itemId}) => {
    
      axios.get(`/api/menu/`, {
        params: {
          Menu: itemId,
        }
      })
      .then(res => {
        const results = res.data;
        this.setState({ results });
        
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
      
    }}
  items={[
      {
        title: 'Pizza',
        itemId: '/menu/Pizza/',
      },
      {
        title: 'Cheese',
        itemId: '/menu/cheese',
      }
    ]}
  />
  </div>
<div class="body">
     this.state.results && this.state.results.map(results => <li>* {results.Name}</li>);
</div>
       </div>
    );
  }
}
```

New app.js

```
import React,{ useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
//import axios from 'axios';
//import { Navigation } from "react-minimal-side-navigation";
//import "react-minimal-side-navigation/lib/ReactMinimalSideNavigation.css";

import MyMenu from './mymenu';

export default class MyList extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      result: [],
    };
    this.callmyapi = this.callmyapi.bind(this);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
     <div class="menu">

   <MyMenu />

   </div>
<div class="body">
     this.state.results && this.state.results.map(results => <li>* {results.Name}</li>);
</div>
       </div>
    );
  }
}
```

New menu file
mymenu.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';
//import MyList from './App.js';

//import { ProSidebar, Menu, MenuItem, SubMenu } from 'react-pro-sidebar';
//import 'react-pro-sidebar/dist/css/styles.css';

import { Navigation } from "react-minimal-side-navigation";
//import Icon from "awesome-react-icons";
import "react-minimal-side-navigation/lib/ReactMinimalSideNavigation.css";

//export default async function MyMenu(){
export default class MyMenu extends React.Component {
  
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      
    };
    
  render() {
    
    return (
      <div>
     

    <Navigation
    // you can use your own router's api to get pathname
    activeItemId="/management/members"
    onSelect={({itemId}) => {
    //  return axios
      axios.get(`/api/menu/`, {
        params: {
        //  Menu: itemId,
        Menu: "meat",
        SubMenu : "burgers"
        }
      })
      .then(res => {
        const results = res.data;
        this.setState({ results });
        
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
      
    }}
  items={[
      {
        title: 'Pizza',
        itemId: '/menu/Pizza/',
      },
      {
        title: 'Cheese',
        itemId: '/menu/cheese',
      }
    ]}
  />
</div>
    );
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

That one is quite easy once you understand state. State is component specific it that case. this.state refers to you App-Component and your Menu-Component individually. So in order for them to share one state you have to pass it down the component tree like this.

```
export default class MyList extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      result: [],
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
     <div class="menu">

   <MyMenu handleStateChange={(results: any[]) => this.setState(results)} />

   </div>
<div class="body">
     this.state.results && this.state.results.map(results => <li>* {results.Name}</li>);
</div>
       </div>
    );
  }
}
```

See this line: <MyMenu handleStateChange={(results: any[]) => this.setState(results)} />
There you pass a function to mutate the state of App-Component down to a the child

There you can call:

```
onSelect={({itemId}) => {
    //  return axios
      axios.get(`/api/menu/`, {
        params: {
        //  Menu: itemId,
        Menu: "meat",
        SubMenu : "burgers"
        }
      })
      .then(res => {
        const results = res.data;
        this.props.handleStateChange(results)
        
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
```

You mutate the parent state and the correct data is being rendered. Make sure to practice state and how it works and how usefull patterns look like to share state between components.

Comment: Hmm its still not passing the data back

Comment: In the menu.js I have added alert(results[1].Name); just before this.props.handleStateChange(results); and that returns a name as it should. but nothing gets displayed in app.js. In addition to your changes I have fixed  this.state = { result: [],}; to results. and put this.state.results..... in curly brackets

Comment: I have updated my code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65996422/react-using-handlestatechange-and-state-to-pass-data-between-react-js-files

Comment: I will help you solve your problem if you set up a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/
and share here. Then i can work with your code and fix the problem myself and tell you about it. Please delete your second question as it creates confusion and does not help us to find the bug. Just copy your code in CSB and we will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks - I Have found solution (also deleted link question)

above render added function

```
handleCallback = (results) =>{
    this.setState({data: results})
}
```

then where I display the menu

```
 <MyMenu parentCallback = {this.handleCallback}/>
```

where i display the results

```
{this.state.results && this.state.results.map(results => <li>{results.Name}</li>}
```

No aditional changes to the menu scripts